# Is this powershell code to install the linux sl command to PowerShell good?

Tags: powershell

I have the following code in my [project](https://github.com/schuelermine/Install-Steam-Locomotive) that installs linux `sl` on Windows using PowerShell. Is there anything you'd improve about this?

```
param([String]$Profile, [Switch]$Help, [Switch]$Force)

$ErrorMessages = @()

$Payload = "
# <Code inserted by Install-Steam-Locomotive>
function Steam-Locomotive {wsl sl -e}
function Steam-Locomotive-Force {wsl sl}
# </>
"

$HelpText = "This script helps you use the tremendous `"sl`" program in Windows PowerShell.
Simply download the .ps1 file and execute it.
If the script finishes successfully, you can type Steam-Locomotive in PS to start the interruptable `"sl -e`".
Use Steam-Locomotive-Force to prevent interruption (`"sl`").
Example:
PS C:\Users\User\Downloads\> .\Install-Steam-Locomotive.ps1 -Profile $PROFILE
"

if ($Help) {
  Write-Output $HelpText
  exit
}

if (!(Get-Command -Name "wsl" -CommandType "Application" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
  $ErrorMessages += @("You don't have WSL installed. Cannot continue.")
}

if (!$Profile) {
  $ErrorMessages += @("Please supply your profile location under -Profile. Cannot continue.")
  if (Get-Content $Profile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-String "Steam-Locomotive") {
    $ErrorMessages += @("Your profile seems to already contain something called `"Steam-Locomotive`". Use -Force to continue anyways.")
  }
}

if ((Get-Command -Name "Steam-Locomotive" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -and !$Force) {
  $ErrorMessages += @("It seems a command named `"Steam-Locomotive`" is already installed. Use -Force to continue anyways.")
}

if ($ErrorMessages) {
  Write-Output $ErrorMessages
  exit
}

if (!(wsl command -v sl)) {
  Write-Output "First, install SL."
  wsl sudo apt install sl
}

if (wsl command -v sl) {
  Add-Content $Profile $Payload
  Write-Output "Done!"
}

if (!(wsl command -v sl)) {
  Write-Output "Failed installing wsl."
  exit
}

Write-Output "Success!"
```

EDIT: I had an error in this script. The fixed version is up on the project page.

Comment: When I read the code, I thought that `wsl` would be the Windows version of `sl`. Nice confusion. :)

Comment: Who or what is `sl`? `Set-Location` is already built-in. Is that the bloody steam locomotive that shows up when using `ls` by mistake in a Windows environment? I usually fix that by actually installing `ls`...

Comment: I'd recommend you [edit] the title to describe/summarize the purpose of the code, as strongly suggested by the watermark in the title textbox. As it stands, any [tag:powershell] question could have that title - and without "powershell" in the title, literally *any on-topic post* on this site could have that title.

Comment: @Mast It's the locomotive that shows up when you type `sl` in linux... if you have it installed. This is if you want the animation in PowerShell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use the [script template](https://gist.github.com/9to5IT/9620683) for documentation
- Use a [cmdlet binding](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_cmdletbindingattribute?view=powershell-7) for parameter
  validation and help text
- Personally, I run with $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"